# Selecting a minimized window in Expose via the trackpad two finger swipe gesture

Tags: trackpad, expose, multi-touch

Normally when you invoke expose, you can use the trackpad's two finger swipe gestures (up, down, left, and right) to highlight a window so that it has a blue border around it. You can then select the window by tapping your third finger down. I really like this method, since it is much quicker than moving the cursor over the window you want and tapping it.

The problem I have noticed is that when you have a minimized window, it will appear below all the other non-minimized windows, separated by a horizontal line. Depending on where the cursor is located (above or below this line) the two finger swipe gesture will only highlight windows within that section (e.g. if you are below the line, you can only highlight minimized windows). Moving the mouse above or below the line will allow you to highlight the corresponding windows.

Is there any way to highlight a window in the opposite section the cursor is located in, without needing to move the cursor?

For example, I want to be able to invoke expose and no matter where my cursor is, I want to be able to select any window I want, using only the two finger swipe gesture.

Comment: Not a trackpad solution, but you could press `down` on your keyboard to access the minimized windows in Exposé — at least this doesn't move your cursor!

Answer (score 1):

Not possible via the trackpad as far as I can tell.  You can use the arrow keys though.